# Why my first request took so long to get response through zuul gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, ribbon, netflix-zuul

I'm using eureka and zull as client discovery and gateway.

But while testing applications, I found that the first request will take a very long time to get response.

I have read springcloud documentation and also checked for stackoverflow to find any solution.

But so far the solutions from google which I found did not solve the problem.

below is part of the configuration:

```
zuul:
  ignored-headers:
    - Vary
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true
  routes:
    resourceCenter:
      path: /web-resource-center/**
      serviceId: web-resource-center
      stripPrefix: true
    messageCenter:
      path: /web-message-center/**
      serviceId: web-message-center
      stripPrefix: true
    webSystem:
      path: /web-system/**
      serviceId: web-system
      stripPrefix: true
    security:
      path: /web-security/**
      serviceId: web-security
      stripPrefix: true
    taskCenter:
      path: /web-task-center/**
      serviceId: web-task-center
      stripPrefix: true
ribbon:
  eager-load:
    enabled: true
    clients:
      - web-resource-center
      - web-task-center
      - web-security
      - web-message-center
      - web-system
```

while not configured, the request will take 2s-4s to get response.

I have configured ribbon and zuul to eager load ,and that may speed up the first request for about 50%

while , the requests after the first one will take only less than 100ms each, I don't know why.

Also one thing here to cunfuse me : If I set a feign request in a controller then request this controller the slow response will not happen. So, are there any mistakes I have made configuring my application.yml?

please help me please,thanks a lot!

Comment: 2s to 4s!! Do you have some lazy beans declaration in your application?

Comment: @akuma8 yes, I think there must be someting lazy beans not configured. I've tried everything I can find on Google about how to speed up my first request, zuul documentation and ribbon documentation, the problem still not solved. As I configured in above, gateway will do eager load at the beggining. But it still take a long time to process the first request.

Comment: @akuma8 After configuring zuul route and eager load,the first request will take about 1s-1.6s, however, after this request, it takes only 100ms per request in average.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem to, when I restart my micro service, the first request though gateway will take 2-3s, and then took less than 100ms. after I configure ribbon eager load, also tooks 600ms. I dont konw how to handle this problem.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: So far I have ignored this situation. Maybe it is due to my currently version of spring cloud dependencies. You have to not only set eager load, but also have to set route of your downstream services in the zuul gateway. That will make the first request more faster. But there are still something which slows down the first request. But considering that case won't lead to any problem, it is acceptable anyway.